# Accessing data from URL query string

Tags: php

How can I use query string variable in second page? For example in page 'a.php' I have generated these links

```
<?php
  echo '<a href="www.domain.com/b.php?id=1">Comedy</a>';
  echo '<a href="www.domain.com/b.php?id=2">Family</a>';
  echo '<a href="www.domain.com/b.php?id=3">Action</a>';
```

Now how I can use the id in page b.php to run a query on database like

```
 SELECT * FROM products WHERE id =
```

As you can see I need to pass the id getting from the URL query string at here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID will be in the $_GET variable:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ' . (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

"SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id"
```

Comment: Thanks Sugumar, do we have to use get? I mean we can't use POST here?

Comment: if you pass the value by url you have use GET and if you use form with method post you can use POST. $_REQUEST[]; can be used for both get and post variables.

Comment: You are not posting, you are passing the variables via GET. You could also use $_REQUEST['id'], that would cover a POST too.

Comment: Remember to cast (int) to make sure the value is an integer as @KiwiJuicer proposed. `$id = (int)$_GET['id'];`

Comment: thank you kek  for notifying me